# SSL Certificates in cPanel

Tags: ssl, cpanel, whm

I have a WHM account that has a ton of accounts/sites in it each with their own cPanel. I'm in the process of updating an expired SSL Cert for one site but I get this warning:

"Your server does not support SNI, so all of your SSL websites must use        the same SSL certificate. An update to the certificate on an existing SSL website will affect all of your SSL websites, and new SSL websites must use   the currently installed certificate."

I wanted to make sure this means just on the domains contained within the cPanel account and not all of the others included in my overall reseller account.

Answer (score 1):

Which OS are you using on your server ? Try to check this with following command.

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

Currently CentOS 6, RHEL 6, or Cloud Linux 6 is required for native SNI support.

SNI would allow you to install multiple certificates on a single IP address.